# How to install OpenJDK 8 on 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, java, openjdk

Java 8 is now available according to http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/, but http://openjdk.java.net/install/ does not yet mention how to install OpenJDK 8 (not Oracle Java) on Ubuntu 14.04 Long Term Support. (For 14.10 and later just run `apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`)

How and when can this be done?

(2017-08-08:  The very short answer is:  **OpenJDK 8 as of 2017-08-08 is not officially available from the official repositories as an APT package for Ubuntu 14.04.**  [See full summary in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/944260/963) - updated 2021-06-29)

Note: For now we will use Oracle Java - the optimal solution for me is, however, OpenJDK from the Ubuntu repositories, until Oracle Java is available directly and effortless from the Ubuntu repositories.

---

Comment: You need to compile it yourself. Here is how: https://github.com/hgomez/obuildfactory/wiki/How-to-build-and-package-OpenJDK-8-on-Linux Change the filename to match version 8 ;-)

Comment: Azul has started providing OpenJDK builds under the name "Zulu" which can be downloaded, unpacked and used automatically.  (They earn their money from support).  http://www.azulsystems.com/products/zulu/downloads

Comment: Notibly, the same ppa that apt-fast for trusty is hosted on, `ppa:saiarcot895/myppa`, has a version of openjdk-8 that works. *shrug*

Comment: As time marches on, it seems that the simplest solution is simply to opgrade 16.04 LTS when available.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of 2017-08-08 I found that this question and its answers had become a bit overwhelming to dig through to understand the issue, so I have summarized the findings in this answer.

The very short answer is that **OpenJDK 8 as of 2017-08-08 is not officially available for Ubuntu 14.04**.

There are however several options available:

- Upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu.  OpenJDK 8 is available from 14.10 and onwards.  (OpenJDK 9 from 16.04 LTS onwards, OpenJDK 11 from 18.04 LTS onward).  Unless you are under extended support this is the best approach as of 2021.
- Download a Azul certified build of OpenJDK 8 from http://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/zulu-linux/ - they have both 64-bit and 32-bit versions.
- Download and install Oracle Java (not OpenJDK) from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html manually as a tar.gz file which just needs to be unpacked and have the license accepted before the `bin` directory can be added to your `$PATH` variable.  You might also choose to use a third party PPA.  **IMPORTANT**: The license was changed in 2019 to be more restrictive and you may need to be a paying customer to use Oracle Java in production!
- Download OpenJDK 8 using a third party PPA. This is an increasingly bad idea as they tend to grow stale or disappear as they are usually made by individuals on a voluntary basis.
- Compile the source and install it yourself.

(Please feel free to add other providers)

See other answers for details.

Personally I would recommend upgrading Ubuntu to 18.04 LTS or newer, or if not possible download a Azul build.  AdoptOpenJDK/Eclipse Adoptium is only an option from 16.04 onwards on x64.

---

Note: If you still need OpenJDK 8 backported to 14.04, vote for this bug by logging in and clicking "Does it affect you" at the top:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1368094

Answer (score 291):

Editors note: This answer is outdated as the PPA’s listed are not available anymore.

---

You can do this for;

### Final Update

**JDK**

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

**JRE**

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

#### Old Update

I found two repository but I do not recommend

- *OpenJDK builds (all archs)*

  ```
    ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
  ```
- *OpenJDK 8 backport for trusty*

  ```
    ppa:jochenkemnade/openjdk-8
  ```

---

#### Original Message

If you really want to use OpenJDK, you have to [compile](https://github.com/hgomez/obuildfactory/wiki/How-to-build-and-package-OpenJDK-8-on-Linux) from source. There is not still any PPA for OpenJDK.

It has been requested at
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1297065

I recommend you to use [Webup8 Oracle Java8 Installer](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html)

> **Note:** WebUpd8 team's PPA has been discontinued with effective from April 16, 2019. Thus this PPA doesn't have any Java files. More information can be found on [PPA's page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). Hence the below method no longer works and exists because of historical reasons.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

To automatically set up the Java 8 environment variables

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Check it

```
java -version
```

So you have to wait to use OpenJDK8

Comment: And why is this more recommended than simply going to the oracle site and downloading Oracle 8 from source?

Comment: @JohnMerlino my guess would be that the PPA allows for automatic updates when new versions are released.

Comment: JohnMerlino Oracle's Java Runtime environment is not free and open-source software! DId you consider that many people refuse to use proprietary software?

Comment: @JohnMerlino there is a difference between getting the sources and compile them and go to the source.  Which one do you mean?

Comment: openjdk-8 is now in Utopic.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1341628 has been raised to backport to 14.04 as it is LTS:

Comment: For the ones that don't have add-apt-repository command run: $ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties

Comment: i am getting error during adding the apt-repo 'softwareproperties.ppa.PPAException: 'Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~webupd8team: [Errno 111] Connection refused'"   --> Any help>?

Comment: More than a year the bug exists and still no resolution fo OpenJDK on U-14.04. Upvote for the oracle java 8 install: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y`...

Comment: @muhasturk: Could you clarify why you don't recommend using those PPAs?

Comment: Why the new edit? It seems to still not be in the 14.04 repo yet and `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk` doesn't work at least for me.

Comment: As of 2016-01-11 the non-official Ubuntu PPA's are still needed, as OpenJDK 8 has not yet landed in backports.  I do not consider this to be an answer to my question even though it appears others do.

Comment: I still can not install it: `Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk`

Comment: This answer is highly misleading due to being incomplete, it says it doesn't recommend the PPA mentioned but won't work without it.

Comment: You need to add the `openjdk-r` ppa. See this answer for the steps clearly defined, http://askubuntu.com/a/666481/216492

Comment: Not working ```E: Package 'openjdk-8-jdk' has no installation candidate```

Comment: The final update part is incorrect. opendk-8-jdk is not in backports. However openjdk-r/ppa does work.

Comment: The request of back-porting Java 8 was raised in 2014, but it has not yet happen. Track [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/trusty-backports/+bug/1368094) (or [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1341628)) for news.

Comment: Down voted because "Final Update" does not work with 14.04 without some kind of additional ppa.

Comment: Doesn't work for me anymore. And it did used to work. These packages are now broken and give 404 errors when I try to install.

Comment: @JohnScott Maybe more people would use OpenJDK if you could just install it in one step without having issues half the time. I reckon most users don't really care and just need it as a requirement to install something else.

Answer (score 202):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Comment: This repository is dated; as of today the latest openjdk 1.8 release is 66. The version available in this repository is 45.

Comment: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk-headless_8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~14.04_amd64.deb  502  apt-cacher: libcurl error: Failure when receiving data from the peer

Comment: These are the correct minimal steps. 4 and 5 are optional and possibly not required.

Comment: Not working for Ubuntu 14.04 ```E: Package 'openjdk-8-jdk' has no installation candidate```

Comment: This worked for me when upgrading Jenkins (newer version required Java8, my system only had Java7 installed). Of note, the fourth line was critical to get Jenkins to behave properly; until running it, I kept getting `Jenkins requires Java8 or later, but you are running 1.7.0_121-b00 from /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre`. Have an upvote... I'd give you more if I could.

Comment: Works also on the Windows Linux subsystem.

Comment: works for me on ubuntu/trusty64 vagrant box

Comment: add-apt-repository: command not found

Comment: As of today it works on ubuntu 14.04 and the JDK version is 1.8.0u222.

Comment: Very helpful, thnks for posting

Answer (score 63):

OpenJDK 8 was released in March 2014. As of the time of this question, there are no OpenJDK 8 packages in the official Ubuntu repositories for any Ubuntu release. They "will be available soon", as the [JDK 8 project page](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/) says, for some definition of soon.

First, the OpenJDK 8 packages will land in the Ubuntu development release. This may happen during the 14.10 development cycle, but there is no set schedule as far as I know. Some preview packages have been built and are available for testing, see the announcement on the [debian-java](https://lists.debian.org/debian-java/2014/04/msg00003.html) and Ubuntu [openjdk](https://lists.launchpad.net/openjdk/msg09995.html) mailing lists. At some point these packages will be uploaded to the Debian and Ubuntu development repositories.

Once OpenJDK 8 is in the Ubuntu development version, then it may be possible to request that it be backported to 14.04. Note that it will never be available in the primary `trusty` repository, but if you use `trusty-backports` then it may be installable from there at some point. Read about the process for requesting backports in Ubuntu [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports).

Comment: I tried to answer your question "how and when" with the constraints that you seem to want: must be from official repositories, must be OpenJDK, and must be the 14.04 LTS release.

Comment: Its Feb 2016, and java 8 is still not available on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. This is disappointing.

Comment: It's April 2016, still no java 8...

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is coming out in April 2016, it will have [OpenJDK 8](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/openjdk-8).

Comment: It's Sep 2016, and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS will still be supported until 2019... and lots of places will take a long time to adopt 16.04 because of larger-scale changes (e.g. systemd), so it's still disappointing java 8 is not easy to install via apt on 14.04 :(

Comment: @geerlingguy please refer to the issue tracker item for adding a [backport of openjdk-8 to 14.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1368094).

Comment: @MikeMiller - Already +1'ed that bug

Comment: It's October 2016, and the OpenJDK 8 package for 14.04 in the [openjdk-r PPA](https://launchpad.net/~openjdk-r/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) hasn't been updated since April 20 ... but it works fine.

Answer (score 36):

## *Note – This will only work with **14.10 or later**:*

1 year late, but as today it works as expected with apt-get.

For installing JDK:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

For installing JRE:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

#### How to set the default JDK

**Fastest way**

Run `$ sudo update-alternatives --config java` and enter the number for which JDK to use of your choice.

**Second way**

List the available JDK's:

```
$ update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1071 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 1069 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Now, to copy & paste the location of Open JDK 8 to match the command below:

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: I still only see JDKs 6 and 7, no openjdk-8-jdk on my Linux 14.04, after sudo apt-get update. Did you add some special repository? I've got trusty-backports enabled.

Comment: I think you're running 14.10 or 15.04, are you not?

Comment: I cannot reproduce on 14.04 LTS.  Please confirm this is the version.

Comment: @akauppi you are right!! I'm running 14.10. Sorry for the inconvenience, should I remove my answer?

Comment: I wouldn't wish it removed - for some, using 14.10 instead of 14.04 might be a perfectly good alternative.

Answer (score 23):

Here's what I use to set up Oracle Java 7 and Java 8 [note: not OpenJDK] from scratch on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

```
apt-get -y -q update
apt-get -y -q upgrade
apt-get -y -q install software-properties-common htop
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
apt-get -y -q update
echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
apt-get -y -q install oracle-java8-installer
apt-get -y -q install oracle-java7-installer
update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle
```

This is unattended and is suitable for inclusion in a Vagrant provision block; I have a gist with more details: https://gist.github.com/tinkerware/cf0c47bb69bf42c2d740

EDIT: This will automatically accept Oracle's license for the JDK; make sure you are okay with that first before running it.

Comment: Looks good. But it is missing the part where you gain root access. Still nice answer.

Comment: Right; I use this with Vagrant, which sets up the `vagrant` user with passwordless `sudo`.

Comment: This is _Oracle_ Java, not _OpenJDK_ Java which was what the question was about.  Also note that the echo lines circument the license acceptance question from the installer.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes, I did notice the question was about OpenJDK; I specifically said that my method is for installing Oracle Java. You may argue that this is not related, but I think there's value in noting an alternative that still gets you a runtime that can run Java 7/8 on 14.04 LTS. "Circumvention" of license acceptance question is an interesting word choice; I would say one should read the Oracle license before running the script, which automates the acceptance during the installation.

Comment: Thanks @Cagatay !!  this answer was very useful for me, I was looking Java 8 installation using Vagrant.

Comment: @Cagatay I think most people will just copy-paste this and see if it works.  In that case no-one will even _know_ that they are silently accepting a license.

Answer (score 5):

**Note** Since 22 April 2016 the packages for Vivid have been removed, alas. News item in packages.ubuntu.com: "Reflect xenial release, add yakkety, remove vivid". The workaround of this answer is clever but no longer applicable in the current situation. As of 6 Jan 2017 there's no backport for java 8 on trusty packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-backports/java yet. Please edit as changes apply.

---

See the answer from Android official site

https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

There are no available supported OpenJDK 8 packages for Ubuntu 14.04. The Ubuntu 15.04 OpenJDK 8 packages have been used successfully with Ubuntu 14.04. Newer package versions (e.g. those for 15.10, 16.04) were found not to work on 14.04 using the instructions below.

Download the .deb packages for your architecture from http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/openjdk-8-jdk:
    openjdk-8-jre-headless
    openjdk-8-jre
    openjdk-8-jdk

Remember, you may obtain the architecture for your machine with:

```
$ uname -m
```

x86_64 represents a 64-bit (amd64) Linux kernel architecture and i386/i486/i586/i686 represents 32-bit (i386) system.

Optionally, confirm the checksums of the downloaded files using the information found on http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/openjdk-8-jdk.

For example with the sha256sum tool:

```
$ sha256sum {package file}
```

Install the packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Run dpkg for each of the .deb files you downloaded. It may produce errors due to missing dependencies:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i {downloaded.deb file}
```

To fix missing dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 4):

I just did vote [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/trusty-backports/+bug/1368094) and now we are 733 people that we do care about backporting openjdk-8 to ubuntu-14.04.

I found [this PPA repository](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/openjdk) is quite uptodate

> and hopefully promising!?

and it worked for me. I was successful to install openjdk-8-jdk on ubuntu-14.04 with following commands:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/openjdk`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

and here is my `java -version` output:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-1~14.04.york0-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

and here is my `uname -a` output:

```
Linux mars1 4.4.0-75-generic #96~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 11:06:30 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and here is my `lsb_release -a` output:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

My virtual-host-server-provider is telling me they only provide support for Ubuntu-14.04 and I am guessing they want to keep going like this until 2019! **so please let me know if you know any better way for having openjdk-8 on ubuntu-14.04?**

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend using Azul Zulu.  http://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/

Comment: I also had to run the following to get it working : `sudo update-java-alternatives --jre --set java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64` and `sudo update-java-alternatives --jre-headless --set java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64`

Answer (score 3):

The [Nix package manager](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix_package_manager) also maintains binary packages of OpenJDK 8 for Ubuntu, meaning you can get a working Java 8 compiler in less than five minutes start to finish (with a fast internet connection, of course).

The steps are:

1. Install the Nix package manager (https://www.domenkozar.com/2014/01/02/getting-started-with-nix-package-manager/): `$ bash <(curl https://nixos.org/nix/install)`
2. Run the shell one-liner Nix tells you to at the end of the installation: `$ . ~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh`
3. Install the OpenJDK Nix package: `$ nix-env -i openjdk`
4. Check `javac`: `$ javac -version`

That's it. Oh, and you'll want to make sure to put the one-liner from step 2 in your `~/.bashrc`. That will tell Nix to link up your installed packages properly (since it keeps the actual files in non-standard directories).

Comment: Out of curiosity - why would you want an additional package manger besides apt-get?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - the specific reason is to quickly get OpenJDK 8 with minimal pain, and the general reason is that Nix is a revolutionary improvement over apt-get and other older package managers.

Comment: I am asking in the general case - not for OpenJDK specifically.  There must be very heavy reasons for introducing a new package manager to outweigh not using the existing ecosystem, which I have a hard time seeing.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - there are very good reasons to recommend Nix in the general case. As I mentioned, it is a revolutionary improvement. On the scale of git over svn. Check out http://www.infoq.com/articles/configuration-management-with-nix for more.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting OpenJDK 8 from the official Debian repositories, rather than some random PPA.  Here's how I did it:

```
sudo apt-get install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring
```

Make `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-jessie-backports.list`:

```
deb http://<httpredir>.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main
```

where you change `<httpredir>` with the prefix for a near mirror (see https://www.debian.org/mirror/list)

Make `/etc/apt/preferences.d/debian-jessie-backports`:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian,a=jessie-backports
Pin-Priority: -200
```

Then finally do the install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: This answer does not work for me. `openjdk-8-jdk` wants `openjdk-8-jre` that wants `libjpeg62-turbo`. According to `apt` this latter is "not installable" or more verbosely "is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source" -- thus not from the repositories I have. The chasing becomes too wide to be wise

Answer (score 1):

It's actually also easy to build the Java 8 yourself directly from sources... Sounds scary? It really is surprisingly easy, and seriously literally takes about 15 minutes, using https://github.com/hgomez/obuildfactory/, as I've described on http://blog2.vorburger.ch/2014/06/build-your-own-jdk-at-home.html

Comment: Building is one thing.  What about the TCK?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I have no idea.  For an individual end-user, self building is already useful IMHO.  For actually preparing a thoroughly tested package, it's probably another story... I'm afraid I know nothing more than you.  I just looked around and found http://openjdk.java.net/groups/conformance/JckAccess/, had you seen that?

Answer (score 1):

Update on Mar 11 2016, run these as root:

```
apt-get update
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DA1A4A13543B466853BAF164EB9B1D8886F44E2A
touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openjdk.list
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu trusty main " >>/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openjdk.list
echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu trusty main" >>/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openjdk.list
apt-get update
apt-get -y install openjdk-8-jdk
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
echo "$JAVA_HOME"
```

Comment: The first line is not needed. The next 4 lines are equivalent to `add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa`. This answer is also a duplicate of older ones.

Comment: In summary (as of 2017-05-02), this is what works for me.
`sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:openjdk-r/ppa; `
`sudo apt-get update; `
`sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk`