# Oracle JDk 8 in Snapcraft App with Maven

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I have a maven project which has source and target versions as JDK 1.8. And I wanted to build a snap app for the same project. As per the [doc](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/snapcraft-parts/) it looks like snapcraft "**will pull a relocatable OpenJDK via the default-jdk Ubuntu package**" and since, my project relies on 1.8 building the app fails. Is there a provision through which I can build the project?

More about [jdk 1.8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464755/how-to-install-openjdk-8-on-14-04-lts) thread.

**Note:** I'm supposed to use only LTS in my environments. I also tried the same in 15.10 but still, snapcraft is using openjdk 7 only. I'm not sure why is this happening.

Comment: I would have the same question. Probably one could just drop in the binaries or oracle's jre.

Comment: This is a known bug that I'm actually assigned to. https://pad.lv/1573509