# Err executing Eclipse Cpp in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to install Eclipse cpp oxygen into Ubuntu 14.04. After extracting the file and executed [eclipse] executable file, i'm met with the following errors. Greatly appreciate any advice fr the community. Thanks!

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.7.0.20170620-1800/splash.bmp
-launcher /opt/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133/eclipse_1624.so
-startup /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 24e806b
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
```

Comment: And you are using java version 1.8?

Comment: hi @Rinzwind, i figured out that it's a java version issue. I've since installed java 1.8 and is able to start  eclipse already. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The notice "requiredJavaVersion=1.8" means you are not using at least Java 1.8.

See for instance [How to install OpenJDK 8 on 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464755/how-to-install-openjdk-8-on-14-04-lts) on how to install 1.8.