# I can't execute eclipse under Ubuntu 18.04 L

Tags: java, launcher, eclipse

I have installed eclipse in my new system Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with `apt-get install eclipse`; but when i'm trying to execute eclipse I got this message on dialog box:`An error occured`
 And  the app stops running.

And in the the log file from Eclipse I see this:

```
!SESSION Thu Apr 11 12:43:08 GMT 2019 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2019-04-11 12:43:08.394
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Could someone give an help ?

Comment: Seems to be a [bug 1784358](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/1784358).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4722827/2908599) you can do this:

> In your `config.ini` file of eclipse `eclipse\configuration\config.ini`
>   check this three things:
>
> ```
> osgi.framework=file\:plugins\\org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.2.R34x_v20080826-1230.jar
> osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.0.v20080604.jar@1\:start
> org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\\bundles.info
> ```
>
> And check whether these jars are in place or not, the jar files depend
>   upon your version of eclipse

You can install OpenJDK 8 using instructions from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/666481/680869). Also there you will find the way to use alternatives.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Comment: It still confuse for me; I don't understand exactly

Comment: Check if you have such records in ini file. And if the `jar` files are on those locations

Comment: This is what i have in the .ini file

Comment: I don't know if it is the same; this is the .ini file I have: `osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.dist.jar `  `osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist.jar@1\:start `  `org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info`  the main differrence is the number replaced with **dist**

Comment: @hackthatos, seems you have them all. Did you check the required version of jdk and what version do you have installed?

Comment: See                                                                                                                                                                                        `openjdk 10.0.2 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4, mixed mode)`

Comment: @hackthatos, IMHO try with OpenJDK 8

Comment: @RomeoNivo You mean I have to install OpenJDK8 despite I have the version 10 already installed?

Comment: @hackthatos, AFAIK you can install both of them and use `alternatives`. Or hardcode in eclipse start script JAVA_HOME to version 8.

Comment: please give me the command to install the other and ue **alternative**; I am novice

Comment: @hackthatos, please check my updated answer

Comment: I have used the `alternative` option. after that i get this this                                                        `openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)`                                              with this command  `java -version` but the problem persists