# How to install Java 13 on Ubuntu 18.04.3? (Works in 20.04 too)

Tags: software-installation, java

How to install Java 13 on Ubuntu 18.04.3  from terminal with sudo privildges?

Comment: https://openjdk.java.net/install/index.html

Comment: There is also a PPA https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/09/install-oracle-java-13-on-ubuntu-linux.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed https://openjdk.java.net/install/index.html per Pilot6 comment (thanks).

JDK 9 & Later

Oracle's OpenJDK JDK binaries for Windows, macOS, and Linux are available on release-specific pages of jdk.java.net as .tar.gz or .zip archives.

As an example, the archives for JDK 13 may be found on jdk.java.net/13 and may be extracted on the command line using

```
$ tar xvf openjdk-13*_bin.tar.gz
```

Commands to download java 15 from jdk net (Linux / x64) using terminal and saving to a folder in Downloads folder called 'j'. ~ is shortcut for current logged in user's home directory

```
mkdir ~/Downloads/j
cd  ~/Downloads/j
curl https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk15.0.2/0d1cfde4252546c6931946de8db48ee2/7/GPL/openjdk-15.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz --output ./jdk_15.0.2_linuxx64bin.tar.gz
 tar xvf j16.tar.gz
```

Used sudo mv to move directory 'jdk-13.0.1' to /usr/lib/jvm/

```
  sudo mv jdk-16  /usr/lib/jvm/
```

Then in my ~/.profile file added/edited (as I had Java 11 before) in text editor:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-13.0.1
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

In the current terminal(s) to reload the profile after changes  gave  command:

```
. ~/.profile
```

Note that its a period, a space and then the file name. Its short hand for the command:

```
source ~/.profile
```

and could use Java 13. Worked after restart too, without running the commands, due to entry in ~/.profile

To test, in terminal give command :
`echo $JAVA_HOME`
Will see out put :

> /usr/lib/jvm/jdk8

You can also set it up as alternatives as in https://askubuntu.com/a/464894/165511 I like to set up the JAVA_HOME variable as need that to run maven etc